# What is the correct name for clearance delivery at KSAN if the tower is called "Lindbergh Tower"?

Tags: air-traffic-control

In the departure and instrument approach charts for KSAN, they reference Lindbergh Tower" for KSAN tower. Does this mean that we should be calling up "Lindbergh Clearance" to pick up our flight plan?

Comment: http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1807/00373IYLY9.PDF  Says on the chart it's SOCAL Approach Control

Comment: I would say it‘s „Lindbergh Delivery“, as usual

Comment: @CrossRoads that is an approach frequency listed on an approach plate.  Nothing to do with CD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lindbergh is used as an identifier shortcut because "Lindbergh Field" is the official name of the airport. So I would call in with "Lindbergh Clearance Delivery".